# Android permissions - regarding permission request conflicts

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, permissions

I have the following code to request a `READ_EXT_STORAGE` permission in the activity's `onCreate()`:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                adb.setMessage("This app needs to read your External Storage/Gallery to provide the images and the music you're going to use in the video.").setPositiveButton("OK", null).create();
                adb.show();
            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXT_STORAGE);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            onCreateActual();
        }
    }
```

Where `onCreateActual()` contains the actual code to be executed in `onCreate()`. It includes setting up the fragments dynamically.

`onStartActual()` involves reading the external storage for picture album names and putting them in a ListView in a fragment.

This is what is in my `onRequestPermissionsResult()`:

```
private int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXT_STORAGE = 102;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Log.i("perms", permissions.length+"");
        int indexOfReadStorage = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < permissions.length; i++)
        {
            Log.i("perms_len", permissions[i]);
            if(permissions[i].contains("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"))
            {
                indexOfReadStorage = i;
            }
        }
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[indexOfReadStorage] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission Granted
            Log.i("read_ext_storage_perm", "granted");
            onCreateActual();
        } else {
            // Permission Denied
            Toast.makeText(this, "READ_EXT_STORAGE Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

My problem is that I have an advertising library that's asking for the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and if I put `onCreateActual()` before this instead of within the else clause, the library asks for that permission first, and the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` above won't be called.

If I do this, however, `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.folders_section, ctrlFragOne, "album_search_results").add(R.id.selection_section, ctrlFragTwo, "indicator").commit();` nets me:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

So, unless there's a much better way, I think I have to somehow stall the lifecycle of the activity until the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is granted.

Is it possible to stall an activity's lifecycle until, say, a variable is changed? If not, can I refresh a Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [Ask](https://github.com/00ec454/Ask) it works well and takes out most of the hastle

just compile dependency

```
compile 'com.vistrav:ask:2.1'
```

and here is the full example

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Ask.on(this)
            .forPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    , Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withRationales("Location permission need for map to work properly",
                    "In order to save file you will need to grant storage permission") //optional
            .go();
}

//optional
@AskGranted(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
public void fileAccessGranted() {
    Log.i(TAG, "FILE  GRANTED");
}

//optional
@AskDenied(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
public void fileAccessDenied() {
    Log.i(TAG, "FILE  DENiED");
}

//optional
@AskGranted(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
public void mapAccessGranted() {
    Log.i(TAG, "MAP GRANTED");
}

//optional
@AskDenied(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
public void mapAccessDenied() {
    Log.i(TAG, "MAP DENIED");
}
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/00ec454/Ask)

Hope it helps